# Android ListView Layouts get mixed up on scroll

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-listview

I have some problems with my custom `ArrayAdapter`.

I have two different layouts which I apply to the list item depending on an object value. Every time I scroll some of the items change where `R.layout.layout1` should be applied, use `R.layout.layout2` or the other way.

I thought of some problems on caching the layouts in the XML file.

The Problem I can´t figure out why the layouts changes on scroll.

**Here is my Java-Code:**

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (this.items.get(position).getId() == this.id)
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1);
        else
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout2);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem1);
        holder.textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem2);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.textView1.setText(this.items.get(position).getInfo1());
    holder.textView2.setText(this.items.get(position).getInfo2());
    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolder {
    public TextView textView1;
    public TextView textView2;
}
```

**And here is the ListView XML part:**

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listViewMessages"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:stackFromBottom="true"
        android:transcriptMode="normal" />
```

Comment: Whats the error/question...? This is a statement

Comment: The Problem I can´t figure out why the layouts changes on scroll.

Comment: So add that on your question for clarity ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your convertView is probably being reused, you have to check when it is different that null, if it is the correct layout and reinflate the correct one.

You can add the layout id to the ViewHolder and check if the convertView is different than null, then inflate the correct layout if the id is different than the one you want.

Something like this:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    ViewHolder holder = null;
    if(convertView == null || ((ViewHolder)convertView.getTag()).id != this.items.get(position).getId())
    {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if(this.items.get(position).getId() == this.id)
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout1);
        else
            convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.layout2);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.textView1 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem1);
        holder.textView2 = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewItem2);
        holder.id = this.items.get(position).getId();
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.textView1.setText(this.items.get(position).getInfo1());
    holder.textView2.setText(this.items.get(position).getInfo2());
    return convertView;
}

public static class ViewHolder
{
    public int id; //Assuming your id is an int, if not, changed it to the correct type
    public TextView textView1;
    public TextView textView2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!! I didn´t realised that I need to check if it is the right layout.

Comment: No problem, it used to happen to me a lot in the beginning :P

Comment: Thanks a lot marco .you save my time