# android list adapter items not correctly shown after scrolling

Tags: android, list, scroll, adapter

The items in my `ListView` are mixed up after scrolling. The problem has something to do with the `adapter` but  I can't figure it out what is  wrong. In my `List` I store several `Events`. If the list become larger, they are mixed up. As an Example events of the current day will by hightlighted but after scolling other titles are highlighted too.

```
public class EintragAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private ArrayList<Event> eventListe;
private final LayoutInflater inflater;
private Context context;

public EintragAdapter(Context c) {
    super();
    eventListe = new ArrayList<>();
    inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    context = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return eventListe.size();
}

@Override
public Event getItem(int position) {
    return eventListe.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return eventListe.isEmpty();
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder;
    final Event event = getItem(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_event, parent, false);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    String endDate = event.getEnd();
    if (endDate.isEmpty()) {
        viewHolder.date.setText(event.getStart());
    } else {
        viewHolder.date.setText(String.format("%1$s %2$s %3$s", event.getStart(), "bis", endDate));
    }

    if (event.isToday()) {
        viewHolder.title.setTextColor(parent.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
    }

    MainActivity mainActivity = (MainActivity) context;
    if (!mainActivity.userIsAdmin()) {
        viewHolder.delete.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

    // viewHolder.timestamp.setText(String.format("%1$s %2$s", "Zuletzt geändert:", event.getTimestamp()));
    if (!event.getDescription().isEmpty())
        viewHolder.description.setText(event.getDescription());
    viewHolder.title.setText(event.getTitle());
    viewHolder.delete.setTag(event);
    return convertView;
}

public void addJSONArray(JSONArray array) throws JSONException {
    if (!eventListe.isEmpty())
        eventListe.clear();

    for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject object = array.getJSONObject(i);
        eventListe.add(new Event(
                object.getInt("id"),
                object.getString("title"),
                object.getString("description"),
                object.getString("start"),
                object.getString("end"),
                object.getString("reg_date")));
    }

    // sort by date - descending
    Collections.sort(eventListe, new Comparator<Event>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Event event1, Event event2) {
            SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.getDefault());

            try {
                Date date1 = format.parse(event1.getStart());
                Date date2 = format.parse(event2.getStart());
                return date1.compareTo(date2);
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return 0;
        }
    });

    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

private static class ViewHolder {
    final TextView title, date, description;
    final View delete;

    ViewHolder(View view) {
        title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_title);
        date = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_date);
        description = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.event_description);
        delete = view.findViewById(R.id.deleteButton);
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Finally I solved my problem using this [Solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32254983/2169712). Thank you for helping

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter class override these two methods

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
   return getCount();
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {
   return position;
}
```

**Edit 1:**

`getViewTypeCount()` should return the number of different views your `ListView` contains. If all of the items in your `ListView` are the same type, you should return 1.

Initially, your `eventListe` is empty and `getCount()` method returning 0 and this is causing the `Exception`.

Change this method with

```
@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
   return getCount()>0?getCount():1;
}
```

Comment: the first method gives an IllegalArgumentException: Can't have a ViewTypeCount < 1

Comment: where you are calling addJSONArray() method in your class(Adapter/Activity).

Comment: I call addJSONArray() in my MainActivity

Comment: you are right but the problem is still present. Is it possible that it is not the adapters fault?

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to make both case (if and else) be handled
like this

```
if (event.isToday()) {
    viewHolder.title.setTextColor(parent.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
}
else{viewHolder.title.setTextColor(/*Default color here*/);}
```

This will solve your highlight problem.
Now modify adapter Constructor as

```
public EintragAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Event> data) {
super();
eventListe = data;  //data not be null
inflater = (LayoutInflater) c.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
context = c;
```

}

Comment: this was only an example. my descriptions are mixed up too

Comment: hightling works correct, only after scolling highlighted titles are mixed up. My solution for highlighting titles is correct because if an event is not today they will stay on their default color.

Comment: pseudo code in Activity UrAdapter ad = new UrAdapter(EventArrayList);

Comment: then list.setAdapter(ad);  EventArrayList.add(content);  ad.notifydatasetchanged();

Comment: I solved my problem. See comment under my original post